# Failed open wikitude in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, native, hybrid

I'm new to Xcode but my project is required to integrate with Wikitude SDK. Can anyone help me or provide any suggestions?

My problem is that I have followed the sample code from [Wikitude IOS](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios) but Xcode throws an error as below when using `cordova.exec` to call this Wikitude SDK.

My error:

> *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  Unable to parse constraint format: 
>   Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
>   |[_architectView]|

My hybrid part:

> cordova.exec(success, fail, "CameraPlugin", "launchCamera", []);

config.xml:

`<feature name="CameraPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CameraPlugin" />
    </feature>`

My class object(CameraPlugin.h):

```
import Cordova/CDV.h

@interface CameraPlugin : CDVPlugin

(void)launchCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

My class object(CameraPlugin.m):

```
-(void)launchCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
NSError *deviceSupportError=nil;


if([WTArchitectView isDeviceSupportedForRequiredFeatures:WTFeature_2DTracking error:&deviceSupportError]) {
        NSLog(@"Device is supported Wikitude SDK");

        //CDVMainViewController *view = (CDVMainViewController*)[self viewController];

        NSLog(@"=== View is configure ===");
        self.architectView = [[WTArchitectView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero motionManager:nil];
        self.architectView.delegate = self;
        self.architectView.debugDelegate = self;

        NSLog(@"=== LicenseKey is configure");
        [self.architectView setLicenseKey:@""];

        NSLog(@"=== URL loading ===");
        self.architectWorldNavigation = [self.architectView loadArchitectWorldFromURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"ArchitectWorld"] withRequiredFeatures:WTFeature_2DTracking];

        NSLog(@"Observer is configure");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:) name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];


        NSLog(@"Subview is configure");
        [self.view addSubview:self.architectView];
        self.architectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_architectView);
        [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_architectView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views] ];
        [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_architectView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views] ];

        NSLog(@"Result is configure");
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"true"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"This device is not supported. Show either an alert or use this class method even before presenting the view controller that manages the WTArchitectView. Error: %@", [deviceSupportError localizedDescription]);
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"true"];
    }

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

Comment: It looks like the view you're trying to add constraints to doesn't exist yet, hence it can't understand the "|" character.
Can you check what the value of self.view is ?

Comment: @FiddleMeRagged : Thanks for reply and self.view is mainView of my project that i was imported into my class which is property (nonatomic, strong) CDVMainViewController *view. 

Below is my CDVMainViewController interface structure :
interface CDVMainViewController : MFPMainViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>